# Maximum sum path in a matrix from top to bottom

Tags: c#, matrix, dynamic-programming

Consider a n*m matrix. Suppose each cell in the matrix has a value assigned. We can start from each cell in first row in matrix. The allowed moves are diagonally left, downwards or diagonally right, i.e, from location `(i, j)` next move can be `(i+1, j)`, or, `(i+1, j+1)`, or `(i+1, j-1)`.  (If index is not outside the bounds of the array of course)

*Let an additional restriction be added: only paths are allowed that pass (at least once) through all the columns.*

Find the maximum sum of elements satisfying the allowed moves.
For example for matrix:

```
1 15 2   
9 7 5
9 2 4   
6 9 -1
```

The sum is equal:

```
28
```

Because the path is `15+5+2+6=28`.

The main feature is that I need to use a dynamic approach. For a task without restriction about all the columns I could do:

```
            var matrix = new int[,]{ { 1, 15, 2 }, //start matrix
                                     { 9, 7, 5 },
                                     { 9, 2, 4},
                                     { 6, 9, -1 } };
            long n = matrix.GetLength(0);
            long m = matrix.GetLength(1);
            
            var sum = new List<long[]>(); // list [n][m] of maxsums 
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                sum.Add(new long[m].Select(e => e = long.MinValue).ToArray());
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                sum[0][i] = matrix[0, i]; //sums at first line equal first line in matrix
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    if (j > 0) sum[i + 1][j - 1] = Math.Max(sum[i][j] + matrix[i + 1, j - 1], sum[i + 1][j - 1]); // diagonally left
                    sum[i + 1][j] = Math.Max(sum[i][j] + matrix[i + 1, j], sum[i + 1][j]); // downwards
                    if (j < m - 1) sum[i + 1][j + 1] = Math.Max(sum[i][j] + matrix[i + 1, j + 1], sum[i + 1][j + 1]); //diagonally right
                }
            }
           
            long max = sum[(int)n - 1].Max(); //maximum sum among all paths (answer)
```

And for the same matrix the maximum sum will equal:

```
42
```

Because the path is `15+9+9+9=42`

Нow I can calculate a dynamics matrix for all paths and sums with restriction?

Comment: Is it September again already?

Comment: I am not sure how this works out to 28. can you show the numbers you are summing to get that

Comment: I think the path is
15+5+2+6=28

Comment: Don't you need to start on the first line ?

Comment: I need. The start line is - 1 15 2

Comment: "*We can start from each cell in first row.*" - this says to me, you can start with 4 or 3 on the first row... I am confused.

Comment: Updated to make that clear

Comment: You are asking for too much. Yes the problem is not trivial, however a solution to the fundamental problem is all you should be needing not a complete solution to your assignment, including input.

Comment: Ie the problem is, how to enumerate paths in a matrix given certain rules. Not that you should be entering in number rows and columns, then entering in space separated values

Comment: This is actually the same problem as a shortest path problem in a general graph. You can apply Dijkstra's algorithm. Due to the "top to bottom" nature of this graph, you can update the results for each node exactly once if you handle them in the correct order, so the execution doesn't even require any extra data structure like a queue of nodes to be updated; and it would be linear in the number of cells in the matrix (ie, Θ(n*m))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this is with a Queue.

1. Add the first row
2. for every item in the queue, add any other valid moves
3. when finished, check if it's a valid combination
4. check against the last highest

It uses an and Iterator method, Linq, and queues to return current best finds. What I suggest you do, is research the parts involved, step through it and inspect variables, use `Console.WriteLine` to look at what is happening. If you are really stuck you can always ask further questions about this code and what it's doing.

The idea of the queue is, we add each element in the first row as initial items in the queue (that is our precondition by the rules you have given), then we go and look at the first element in the queue, then from that position (x,y) we go through all the next positions in the next row that we can legitimately visit. The queue also hold a list of columns visited and a value at that position. It could be done differently. I.e we really only need to to know the sum of all elements visited and a list of columns etc so we can validate the path afterwards.

<sub>***Note** : This is not the most optimal solution and it could be done a lot more efficiently and in less code in many other ways (and more elegantly). However, it touches on a lot of common concepts that are worth understanding*</sub>

**Given**

```
private static Random _rand = new Random();

// this could be done with linq, however it's easy to see how it works
private static bool IsPathValid(int length, List<int> path)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        if (!path.Contains(i))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

**Iterator**

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<(int col, int value)>> FindPath(int[, ] matrix)
{
    var queue = new Queue<(int x, int y, List<(int col, int value)> path)>();
    // add the first row to the queue
    for (var i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(1); i++)
        queue.Enqueue((i, 0, new List<(int col, int value)>()));
    // lets keep the higest found
    var highest = int.MinValue;
    // loop all queue items until none left
    while (queue.Any())
    {
        // get the next item out of the queue
        var(x, y, path) = queue.Dequeue();
        // add the path we are visiting
        path.Add((x, matrix[y, x]));
        // if we have looked at all the rows, then time to return
        if (y + 1 == matrix.GetLength(0))
        {
            // get a list of columns visited 
            var cols = path.Select(x => x.col).ToList();
            // check to see if all columns are visited
            if (IsPathValid(matrix.GetLength(1), cols))
            {
                var sum = path.Sum(x => x.value);
                // sum the path, if it's not the highest we don't care
                if (sum > highest)
                {
                    // we are the highest path so far so let's return it
                    yield return path;
                    highest = sum;
                }
            }

            continue;
        }

        // where ever we are, lets look at all the valid x's in the next row
        var start = Math.Max(0, x - 1);
        var finish = Math.Min(matrix.GetLength(1) - 1, x + 1);
        // add them to the queue
        // we inefficiently create a new path, as list is a reference type and we don't want to reuse it
        for (var newX = start; newX <= finish; newX++)
            queue.Enqueue((newX, y + 1, new List<(int col, int value)>(path)));
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
// create a random matrix, make sure there the dimensions are going to produce a result
var y = _rand.Next(2, 5);
var matrix = new int[_rand.Next(y, y + 3), y];

// fill and print the matrix
Console.WriteLine("Matrix");
Console.WriteLine();
for (var i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
{
   for (var j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
   {
      matrix[i, j] = _rand.Next(0, 20);
      Console.Write(matrix[i, j].ToString().PadLeft(3));
   }

   Console.WriteLine();
}


Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Best Path (column,Value)");
Console.WriteLine();

// get the best, which be the last
var best = FindPath(matrix).Last();
foreach (var item in best)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item);
}

// show the result
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("= " + best.Sum(x => x.value));
```

**Output**

```
Matrix

 14  9 17  0
 19  5 11 10
 17 12  9 13
  3 11  2  5
  0  0 12 15

Best Path (column,Value)

(0, 14)
(0, 19)
(1, 12)
(2, 2)
(3, 15)

= 62
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vDyN5F)

---

**Additional Resources**

- [Iterators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/iterators)
- [Tuple types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples)
- [Array.GetLength(Int32) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getlength?view=netcore-3.1)
- [Multidimensional Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays)
- [Random.Next Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netcore-3.1)
- [Queue Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=netcore-3.1)
- [List.Contains(T) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=netcore-3.1)
- [Enumerable.Any Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netcore-3.1)
- [Enumerable.Sum Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netcore-3.1)
- [Enumerable.Last Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.last?view=netcore-3.1)
- [Math.Min Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.min?view=netcore-3.1)
- [Math.Max Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.max?view=netcore-3.1)
- [continue (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/continue)
- [Enumerable.Select Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1)
- [Enumerable.ToList methd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: I added a few more clarifications, unfortunately your approach requires too much memory for my tests.

Comment: @kate, i can create a much more efficient algorithm that would use minimal memory could fast path the processing

Comment: I really want to understand how to implement a solution using only dynamic programming, as I did for a more general problem before

Comment: @Kate please define dynamic programing.

Comment: @Kate that's to say, you can either fix the memory, or fix the processing. I could give you a solution that is the most efficient at processing (fastest) however it would requier more memory, or I could give you a solution that saves memory yet would take more processing

Comment: Then it would be great to reduce memory usage

Comment: @Kate with the columns ever exceed 64 ?

Comment: columns can be up to 768
and lines up to 1024